# How to find frequency of a field based on another attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, frequency

I'm working in ArcMap. I have a list of people and the states that they live in. Small Example:

[image]

I want to know what is the most common name in each state.

I thought I would use the frequency tool to return unique values of names, but I want to know the frequency for each state. Is there a way to do this without doing the frequency tool 50 times for each state?

Comment: Set the case field to be state and count on person.

Comment: Doesn't that just return a count of the unique names found in each state? How would I find the most common name?

Comment: Conctenate fields, use frequency on that. Split field in result table, sort by frequency and delete duplicates by state.